# How to out all the int values from a string array and store that int values in another array

Tags: c#, arrays

There are words and int values in a string array. My goal is to retrieve the int values from another array. I have seen two methods for converting and finding int values from a string array.

To get all the int values from the string, I first create another int array and use an Array.ConvertAll init. The second method is to loop through isDigit().

Now, the problem is that I cannot find a way to store that value in an int array that has been converted to an int. The final goal is to find the minimum and maximum value from the converted values.

```
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };
int result;
int[] num = Array.ConvertAll(strArray1, x =>
{
    bool convertStrIntoInt = int.TryParse(x, out  int result);
    return result;
});
```

In here, I don't how to get the result outside of it to do a sort to find min and max values.

Comment: Don't use `ConvertAll` because you're not converting all. You're only converting the elements that can be converted. Use a loop or else a LINQ query with `Where`.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to do that. All I need to do is convert the string values into int and then want to max and min the values, but I'd like to do it in a more logical manner, not by using a predefined method, so if possible, please show me a way to do it logically by using methods that do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand what you want but if you want only int then use this

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
        string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };
        foreach (string str in strArray1)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(str, out int val))
            {
                list.Add(val);
            }
        }
        int[] vs = list.ToArray();
```

now all the int values are stored in vs array, if there are some words which contains the int value and you want them to be extracted you can use regex to find the digits in word also

Comment: may i ask that why you declare a list instead of array? then you cast it to array? declare an `int[]` and append values inside it?

Comment: because working with a `List<int>` is much easier than working with an `int[]`. You cannot, e.g. append values to an int array: when you create an array with a new int[10], the size of the array is fixed to 10. Array are seldom the right data structure to use in c#

Comment: @GianPaolo - Arrays are often the right data structure. There are many more times that you don't want to allow code to add to a collection of items.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use LINQ for this:

```
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };

int[] num =
(
    from x in strArray1
    let n = int.TryParse(x, out int n) ? (int?)n : null
    where n.HasValue
    select n.Value
).ToArray();
```

That outputs:

[image: num]

Then you can do this:

```
int max = num.Max();
int min = num.Min();
```

Comment: Not sure if you understand, but I also want to calculate a minimum and maximum value from the converted, and use it logically without using a predefined function

In addition, it is important to find the maximum value of that

Then I want to access int n outside of that int[]

In order to find the minimum and maximum values

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Regex` like below :

```
string[] strArray1 = {"Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109"};

int[] num = strArray1.Where(v => Regex.IsMatch(v, @"^\d+$")).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();


int min = num.Min();
int max = num.Max();
```

As you don't want to use `Regex`, you can go with your solution, just do a small modification to get your desired result. Try this :

```
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };
int[] num = Array.ConvertAll(strArray1, x =>
{
    bool convertStrIntoInt = int.TryParse(x, out int result);
    return result;
}).Where(x => x > 0).ToArray();

int max = num.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToArray()[0];
int min = num.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()[0];
```

Comment: It's going to be a `string[]` but he wants an `int[]` I guess

Comment: @Alp You are right, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Little optimized solution could be something like below

```
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };
var numArray = strArray1.Where(var=> new Regex(@"^\d+").IsMatch(var)).ToArray();
var res = Array.ConvertAll(numArray,s => int.Parse(s));
```

If we don't want to use Regex can try something like below

```
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };
int testNum;
var numArray = strArray1.Where(var=> int.TryParse(var,out testNum)).ToArray();
var res = Array.ConvertAll(numArray,s => int.Parse(s));
```

You can then get max and min value using

> res.Min(), res.Max()

This should give you a starting point for your problem

Comment: as i said i dont want to use any function (regex), i can only use isDigit or try parse methdo

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get int values from a string array into an int array.

Try it on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kscBrp).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int[] ToIntegerArray(this string[] sender)
    {

        var intArray = Array
            .ConvertAll(sender,
                (input) => new {
                    IsInteger = int.TryParse(input, out var integerValue),
                    Value = integerValue
                })
            .Where(result => result.IsInteger)
            .Select(result => result.Value)
            .ToArray();

        return intArray;

    }
}
```

Use

```
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };
int[] intArray = strArray1.ToIntegerArray();
Array.Sort(intArray);
foreach (var value in intArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Min: {intArray.Min()}");
Console.WriteLine($"Max: {intArray.Max()}");
```

Answer (score -1):

Targeting your intial question:

> I don't [know] how to get the result outside of it to do a sort to find min and max values.

You simply can't get a complete solution for your Problem using `ConvertAll()` with a "normal" `int`.

So if we take a look at your result:

```
int[] num = Array.ConvertAll(strArray1, x =>
{
    bool convertStrIntoInt = int.TryParse(x, out int result);
    return result;
});

// num: int[8] { 0, 99, 0, 3, 0, 12, 0, 109 }
```

We can see each word will result in a `0`, since `0` will be returned if the parsing failed - see: [`Int32.TryParse(...)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,958cb8bc00d00a94).
And therefore it is impossible to differentiate between an real `0` in your input or a word, which could not be parsed.

**But** we can tweek the convert a little bit by using `Nullable<int>`/`int?`

```
int?[] num = Array.ConvertAll(strArray1, x =>
{
    return (int?)( int.TryParse(x, out  int result) ? result : null);
});

// num: Nullable<int>[8] { null, 99, null, 3, null, 12, null, 109 }
```

So with this we are able to differ between a `0` and a word - represented by `null`.

Now you can perform other operations like `num.Max()` and `num.Min()`.
If you need an `int[]` array, you have add some more function calls.

```
int[] num = Array.ConvertAll(strArray1, x =>
{
    return (int?)( int.TryParse(x, out  int result) ? result : null);
}).OfType<int>().ToArray();

//num: int[4] { 99, 3, 12, 109 }
```

So this is not quite optimal.

---

My solution for this would be a simple loop.

```
// Your intput
string[] strArray1 = { "Bautik", "99", "Sagar", "3", "Tisha", "12", "Riya", "109" };

// Output Variables
List<int> result = new();
int min = int.MaxValue; 
int max = int.MinValue;

// Loop
foreach( string item in strArray1)
{ 
    if(int.TryParse(item, out int value))
    { 
        result.Add(value);
        min = min > value ? value : min;
        max = max < value ? value : max;
     }
}

// Output
// result: List<int>[4] { 99, 3, 12, 109 }
// min: 3
// max: 109
```

---

As already mentioned by [Gian Paolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276027) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231208/how-to-out-all-the-int-values-from-a-string-array-and-store-that-int-values-in-a#comment129332906_73231323) of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231323/5893316)

> working with a `List<int>` is much easier than working with an `int[]`

..., but if you really need an array, then you can just call [`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=net-6.0).

```
int[] resultArray = result.ToArray();
```

Which results in `int[4] { 99, 3, 12, 109 }`.